# Why does my SmartTarget-enabled Deployer need to know about the Fredhopper Query Server?

Tags: smarttarget, deployer

In smarttarget_conf.xml there is a section where you configure connection details for the Fredhopper Query Service (the `<QueryServer>` element). This configuration file is required in a SmartTarget enabled deployer, however my understanding is that when you deploy content to SmartTarget/Fredhopper, that you only connect to the Index Server. As such I tried removing this element, but publishing failed saying that this configuration setting was missing. Is there a reason why the QueryServer needs to be configured?

Answer (score 2):

The 'smarttarget_conf.xml' configuration file is the same for the CD deployer, CD web service and website web applications.

On the CD deployer the query server settings are not used. You can put in bogus settings for that part as long as the configuration elements have some value.

Comment: Jan is absolutely correct. The underlying reason is basically that the configuration settings code is the same everywhere. It validates all of the mandatory settings on load, no matter if they are used in that context or not. We'll be looking at improving that in a future version, although I cannot say exactly when that will happen.